# Replace <span> element with var containing html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable i lifted the contents of, from a div on the page, like so:

```
var originContents = $('#origin .teleportMe').html();
```

there is a set of span tags, with class="insertionPoint" on the page, i would like to remove and replace with the contents of the origin div.

i would prefer to do this with jquery but not essential.

replace this with the contents of: originContents

```
<span class="insertionPoint">insert</span>
```

Oh and hide the original after complete.

Comment: Why not create your own element then just replace the entire span element with your own element, so the span is now disconnected from the tree and can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('.insertionPoint').replaceWith(originContents);
$('#origin .teleportMe').hide();
```

See [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) and [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/). But note that if the HTML contains elements with IDs and the HTML is now inserted into multiple places, using these IDs might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Can i swap it out then instead of hiding the original, to maintain full functionality of css and all..